Anything that can be felt, is therefore real
Greetings
I have recently been reading the lyrical meanings of a song, and other people's interpretations.
With a small background in Philosophy, I took notice of a simple statement in someone's rather long criticism:
"Anything that can be felt, is real."
( Feeling is referring to different human senses regarding Love, Kindness, Hatred Etc... )
This statement is somehow referring to Christian thought, but I would like to set that acknowledgement aside and analyze the statement through pure logic.
Is it actually correct?
Why/Why not?

Indeed as Berkeley's dictum to be is to be perceived...

"Simple statements" presuppose a lot of things implied by their context. There is no point analyzing them "through pure logic" because "pure logic" says nothing about the meaning of words in them. And "felt" and "real" are some notoriously vague words, there is no telling whether some sentence with them is true without knowing what was meant by those words. So what was the context of this "simple statement" in the "long criticism"?

Take a look at the studies about Attribution Theory, i.e. the way we assign a cause to our everyday experience.
For example if I see a shadow moving on the wall of my bedroom at night, I could assign it to a tree moving in the wind, a robber looking by my window or a ghost coming to haunt me, or a pure hallucination from my sleepy brain.
Usually our brain is going to chose one of those interpretations and devise an action to react to the situation (no action, in the case of an inofensive tree, being a possibility as well). We have a bias toward action, because innaction gets you killed in nature, so it is very unnatural to pause and remind ourself that we don't know and should delay the decision. My perception of the moving light is real, even if it was an hallucination happening only in my brain, the fact that this is what I perceive is just a given fact. However, the cause I assigned to this perception may not be real: I could think there is a ghost when actually it's the wind in a tree.
This is the fundamental distinction the song you are referencing is missing. What one feels, the euphoria, the joy, the kindness is real. By the mere fact that they feel it, the feeling is undoubtly real, by definition. What might very well not be real is the cause attributed to this feeling, in this case some kind of supernatural being who would magically provoke this feeling. It might just be that they are together with a bunch of like minded people, stress free, singing and releasing endorphine into their brains.

You are looking for effect in general, not simply feeling.
What has any effect is real.
Falsehoods, delusions, illusions, abstract concepts, the hypothetical have an effect above nothing. Therefore, they are real. Real by at least their effect.
Falsehoods and delusions shaped civilizations.
Sciences constantly dwell in the hypothetical to disprove statements.
Sciences apply incomplete models and approximations (e.g. mass points, Newtons mechanics) instead of correct representations of "reality" all over the place.
Still, one can not deny their effect and call these things unreal.
When people call these things unreal they usually identify real things by their expected essence, not their effect. This is a mistake. They will call it unreal but suffer its effect and act upon the effect anyway.
When Kant stated "I think, therefore I am.", he only experienced the effect of his thoughts onto himself. He did not identify the essence of his thoughts.
Here, also be aware of the differences between effect, utility and truth:
Effect is simply what causes a state difference between the world where the effect applied and the world where it didn't (and other things being the same aka. experimental conditions).
Utility requires effect but is highly subjective. An effect, that is good for you, may be bad for someone else.
Truth does not imply utility. A truth may be useful.
Falsehood does not imply utility. A falsehood may be useful.
Truth is overrated and does not define (complete) reality.

Consequently, calling something real is not calling it truth. "I have 3 heads." is real, a real falsehood. God is real, but does not have to be the truth. Real => True is a fallacious reasoning many people fall for.

Everything is real, but not everything is the truth. Reality consists of polarities like hot/cold, small/big, .... and most importantly true/false. Truth is only a small subset of reality. Only one pol in one of many polarities. Equating truth to reality is partial denial of reality.
